# Use an external database in Django app on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to deploy a Django REST API on Heroku. Normally I wouldn't have any issues with this but for this app, I am using a legacy database that exists on AWS. Is it possible for me to continue to use this remote database after deploying Django to Heroku? I have the database credentials all set up in settings.py so I would assume that it should work but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not pose any problem to connect with an database on AWS.

But be sure that the database on AWS is configured to accept external access, so that Heroku can connect.

And I would sugest that you take the credentials out of the source code and put it in the Config Vars that Heroku provide (environment variables).

Comment: Thank you for the response. That is what I assumed. I just wasn’t sure if Heroku would still try to create a database and use it. Are the Config Vars on Heroku the same as environment variables in a .env file? (I.e. can I get rid of my .env file and put my database and Django env variables directly into Heroku config vars?)

Comment: Yes. The Config Vars are the Enviroment Variables that Heroku uses. So you will not need ".env" file.

Comment: If you need to improve the security of the database latter, you can try out the AWS Elastic Beanstalk, it's similar to Heroku, but you will be able to keep under the same server and protect the database server from external access.

Comment: I had thought about that too. The existing database is a part of an existing elastic beanstalk application/environment. Is it possible to deploy this Django app to elastic beanstalk but use the existing database in the the other elastic beanstalk app?

Comment: It should pose no problem just to reuse the database in another beanstalk app. An Beanstalk App can connect with any database without a problem (same as Heroku).

Comment: Great. Thank you for your help. I will give that a try.

Comment: The problem that you may have is that if your existing database was created by an Beanstalk App, if that beanstalk app is excluded, you will lost your database server.

Comment: That is the situation I am in. I believe the database was created by the beanstalk app and is tied to it.

Comment: You can see if it is tied to it on the configurations of the Beanstalk App. If it shows the RDS on it's configurations, then it's tied. If the app doesn't use the enviroment variables named RDS, and also don't shows RDS on it's configuration, then it's not tied. But you should try to move that database to one server that you can control, be it an EC2 machine or one RDS manually created.

Answer (score 0):

Will it work? I think yes, provided you configure your project and database for external access.

Should you want it? How may queries does an average page execute? Some applications may make tens of queries for every endpoint and added wait can combine into seconds of waiting for every request.

Comment: I will probably not be making more that 3 or 4 queries per endpoint. That was one of the things I was concerned about. I guess I will have to wait and see.

Comment: There also may be some security concerns. I wouldn't want to forward my db ports to internet.